# How to shorten webpack stack trace?

Tags: angular, logging, webpack, stack-trace

I've just migrated me Angular2 app from SystemJS to webpack. All fine, but I've already got tired of scrolling exceptions' stack traces.

One exception produces 716 lines of stack trace in console!!!

I've uploaded full stack trace to git: https://github.com/sinedsem/test/blob/master/stack_trace.txt

I would like to leave only one part of that messages, where I can see original file and line in file: Here is the example:

[image: good part of stack trace]

Any way I can achieve this?

Webpack configuration the same as in https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

Comment: can you add yout webpack config file(s) ?

Comment: @stackdave I've changed nothing from here: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter

Answer (score 1):

I found one workaround: to use ".ts" filter in Chrome dev tools. This leaves only one short message I showed above in the screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 2 webpack starter is very complex; has too much things; and if in your project has need something different, or if there is some different it will be hard to debug error.

Try use webpack guide from the angular2 website:

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

by example angularclass is not updated with every new version from angular2.
Example in package.json;
From angular site you will find last version: "@angular/common": "~2.4.0"
From the angularclass: "@angular/common": "~2.4.0",

it's important you understand how works webpack, since a more simple settings , to modify and add things later.

my webpack.common.js changed is:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

var helpers = require('./helpers');


module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
        'app': './src/main.ts'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html']
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                loader: 'raw'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader'
                )
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                loader: 'raw!css!postcss-loader!sass'
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json-loader'
            }
        ]
    },

    postcss: function (webpack) {
        return [
            autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 10 versions']}),
        ];
    },

    plugins: [

        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html'
        }),


        new ExtractTextPlugin('css/[name].css')


    ]

};
```

I've added saas support and autoprefixer.